# Remove redundant template types

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently struggling with templates: I have a templated class `A`, which performs basic math (for floats, doubles, complex numbers) and looks like this

```
template <typename T>
class A
{  
public:
    void foo(std::vector<std::complex<T>>& result);
};
```

Now I can use the class like `A<double>, A<float>`, but I would also like to use it like `A<std::complex<float>>` and `A<std::complex<double>>`. When using the latter, I would like the definition of `foo` to look like

```
void foo(std::vector<std::complex<float>>& result);
```

and not like

```
void foo(std::vector<std::complex<std::complex<float>>>& result);
```

Is there any way to create a specific template for the `std::complex<T>` cases, in which I can access the "inner" type? Or this is not possible/bad practice?
What is the most elegant way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way can pass through the creation of a type traits to detect the (extract, when needed) the float type

```
template <typename T>
struct getFloatType
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct getFloatType<std::complex<T>>
 { using type = T; };
```

and use it in `A` (see `fT`)

```
template <typename T>
class A
 {  
   public:
      using fT = typename getFloatType<T>::type;

      void foo(std::vector<std::complex<fT>>& result)
       { }
 };
```

Comment: Are these two ways equal, or is one of them the preferred way to do this?

Comment: @FlashTek - they are really different; in this way you can avoid to create a specialization that can be an advantage; but a specialization can be needed for other reasons; in this toy example I think it's preferred the type traits way; but for your real (I suppose more complex) necessity, the specialization way can be preferable. Only you can give and answer to your question.

Comment: @FlashTek If you just want to change the signature of `foo` then this one is simpler. With partial specialization you can customize more things, but as you asked you have to handle the duplicated codes between primary template and partial specialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for any instantiation of `std::complex`, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
class A<std::complex<T>>
{  
public:
    void foo(std::vector<std::complex<T>>& result);
};
```

Then for `A<std::complex<double>>`, the signature of `foo` would be `void foo(std::vector<std::complex<double>>& result);`.

To handle those duplicated codes, you can make a base class and move the common members into it, and make the primary template and partial specialization both derive from it. e.g.

```
class Base {
public:
    void bar(...);
};
```

then

```
template <typename T>
class A : public Base {
    ...
};

template <typename T>
class A<std::complex<T>> : public Base {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Assuming I have other functions inside the `A` class, do I need to add the definitions of these in the partial specification, too?

Comment: @FlashTek Yes. You can make a base class and move the common members into it, and make the primary template and partial specialization both derive from it.

Comment: When I declare the function inside a header, and define it in the body/cpp, can I reuse the code, or do I need to add the definition inside the cpp twice?

Comment: @FlashTek If you define it in a cpp you will run into problems.

Comment: @FlashTek Yes you can declare firstly, and define later. But you'd better put them all in header file. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1)

Comment: But when I store it all in the header I cannot reuse the code, correct?

Comment: @FlashTek What do you mean can't reuse? You can include the header file and use them ?

Comment: No, by reusing I meant to use the same code/definition for the same function, once for the general template class and once for the specialized class.

Comment: @FlashTek As I said, you can add a base class for common code. For templates, you'd better declare and implement all in header file, Ohterwise, you can declare in header and implement in cpp file as the usual class.

Comment: @FlashTek I added a draft about duplicated code. Is that clear?